# How to easily count the number of matches of a glob involving paths with spaces?

Tags: bash

I am dealing with paths that will have spaces.

I am globbing this way (the second line sets up the glob):

```
IFS=$'\n'

VAR="$1/"name_*

for file in $VAR; do
  echo $file
  grep ITEM "$file" | wc -l
done
```

I need to look only in files that are named `name_*` under `$1`. The `IFS` I set here lets me look at the files properly, because it prevents the `for` from becoming tripped up by spaces in filenames.

However, I now want an easy way to grab the total number of such files matched by the glob. I know I can use a counter in the for loop, but I was hoping I could use a pipe with my `VAR` to do this.

However, if I `echo $VAR`, the globbing occurs successfully, but the different paths are joined by space, which ruins me because I can now no longer separate the items... Is there a way to override this behavior similar to how IFS works on `for`?

Comment: Another approach that satisfies the requirement but without directly answering the question is to filter (using `grep` or whatnot) the output of `ls` or whatnot, rather than to glob the path.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using/expanding strings if what you want is a list of separated values.

The basic solution is to set the positional parameters:

```
set -- "$1"/name_*
```

That will keep each matched file in one separated positional parameter even with spaces or newlines (or most other characters).

In bash, you should set `shopt -s failglob` to make the script stop if no file is matched by the glob (`*`), or `shopt -s nullglob` if you want to get no result (as opposed to the glob itself `"$1"/name_*`) if the glob fails to match any file. Keep failglob unset to avoid stopping the script.

The count of files (*count the number of matches of a glob*) is now simply:

```
echo "$#"
```

the count of positional parameters.

The for loop would reduce to:

```
for file
do  echo "$file"
done
```

That completely avoid problems with splitting on `IFS`.

Note that external values `$1` must be quoted to avoid code injection.
As also does the `echo "$file"` should be quoted.

It is also possible to assign a list to an array:

```
files=( "$1"/name_* )
```

That will avoid clobbering the positional parameters, but will make the syntax a bit more complex. The count of elements in the array is:

```
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

And the loop will need some change:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the problem of spaces *and* get the count if you switched to using arrays:

```
VAR=("$1/"name_*) # make array of filenames matching glob

echo "${#VAR[@]}" # number of elements in array

for file in "${VAR[@]}"; do  # loop over individual elements of array
  echo "$file"
  grep ITEM "$file" -c  # grep can count, wc isn't needed
done
```