# Iterating over files in Bash and obtaining the index and the counts

Tags: shell-script

The [proper way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162586/proper-way-to-iterate-through-contents-in-a-directory) to iterate over files in a directory in Bash is using "for loop" and glob as following:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    echo "- Processing file: $f"
done
```

But how can I retrieve the total count of the files and the current index of the loop interaction? I need the total count, not the cumulative count to show the progress.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would store the list of files in an [array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472668/18887), so that you don't have to read the file system twice, increasing performance and reducing potential race conditions. Then use another variable as the index.

```
files=(*.jpg)
total=${#files[@]}
i=0
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    echo index $i
    echo total $total
    echo "- Processing file: $f"
done
```

#### Explanation

- `files=(*.jpg)`: store the glob into the array `$files`
- `total=${#files[@]}`: read the total into `$total`
- `i=0`: initialise `$i` to 0.
- `i=$(( i + 1 ))`: add 1 to `$i` each loop

This presumes that the "first" loop is 1. Depending on your opinion, you might want to start at 0 instead.